# I want to get all the weeks of a month with the start and end dates of those weeks without creating a table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, datetime, date

My SQL is:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', '2020-06-01'::timestamp)::date ||'-'|| 
(date_trunc('week', '2020-06-01'::timestamp)+ '6 days'::interval)::date;
```

However, using this code it shows only one week's output (2020-06-01-2020-06-07). The actual output I want is:

```
 (2020-06-01-2020-06-07,
 2020-06-08-2020-06-14,
 2020-06-15-2020-06-21,
 2020-06-22-2020-06-28)
```

Answer (score 1):

[generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) with timestamp arguments will do what you want.

```
testdb=# select d::date::text||'-'||(d+interval '6 days')::date::text from
generate_series('2020-06-01', '2020-06-01'::date + interval '3 weeks', interval '1 weeks') d;
       ?column?        
-----------------------
 2020-06-01-2020-06-07
 2020-06-08-2020-06-14
 2020-06-15-2020-06-21
 2020-06-22-2020-06-28
(4 rows)

Time: 0.645 ms
```

Comment: Nice one (+1) - I'll adapt this to my solution to have fewer CTEs!  However, I believe that the OP wants the answer as a single string and not separate fields - see my (edited) answer.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

Thanks to the answer by @AdamKG [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/268591/34007), it is possible to obtain the exact result desired by the OP in one pass **without** using [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html)s as follows (fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d2cbed328f8257475f933d34d3e37052)):

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE
  (
    '(' ||
    STRING_AGG(d::DATE::TEXT || '-' || (d + INTERVAL '6 days')::DATE::TEXT || ',' , E'\n') 
    || ')', ',)', ')'
  ) AS str
FROM GENERATE_SERIES
     (
       '2020-06-01', '2020-06-01'::DATE + INTERVAL '3 weeks', INTERVAL '1 weeks'
     ) d;
```

Result:

```
str
(2020-06-01-2020-06-07,
2020-06-08-2020-06-14,
2020-06-15-2020-06-21,
2020-06-22-2020-06-28)
```

*Et voilà bis*.

I'm leaving my original answer intact below for those who wish to follow the logic - it's essentially the same as the query above except it's all done in one step!

---

### Original Answer:

This proved tricky enough to get **exactly** into the requested format, but I was able to get there eventually! A 9.6 fiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6310197d70be6e56bdbf7aed40524510).

### This SQL finally did it:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT t.d1::DATE
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES
       (
         TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01',
         TIMESTAMP '2020-06-30',
         INTERVAL  '7 DAY'
       ) AS t(d1)
),
cte2 AS
(
  SELECT d1, (d1 + '6 DAY'::INTERVAL)::DATE AS d2
  FROM cte1
  WHERE (d1 + '6 DAY'::INTERVAL)::DATE < '2020-06-30'::DATE
),
cte3 AS
(
  SELECT 
    '(' || 
    STRING_AGG((d1::TEXT) || '-' || (d2::TEXT) || ',', E'\n') 
    || ')' 
    AS date_string1
  FROM cte2
)
SELECT REPLACE(date_string1, ',)', ')') AS date_string FROM cte3;
```

### Result:

```
date_string
(2020-06-01-2020-06-07,
2020-06-08-2020-06-14,
2020-06-15-2020-06-21,
2020-06-22-2020-06-28)
```

which is exactly the format requested!

### Logic:

I'll go through the logic step by step, since `a)` I believe that it's helpful to the OP and `b)` it's helpful for me to reinforce what I've learnt in answering the question (+1 for a thought-provoking quesion BTW). The steps are also outlined in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6310197d70be6e56bdbf7aed40524510)!

### `cte1`

Here, I make use of the (**incredibly** useful) [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-srf.html) function. This gets all the Mondays in June - it may be a coincidence that June 2020 starts with a Monday - but anyway, that's what the OP wants - in any case, if it's Mondays from other months that are required, you only have to start from the relevant first Monday. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/470530) very helpful for this section!

```
SELECT t.d1::DATE
FROM GENERATE_SERIES
     (
       TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01',
       TIMESTAMP '2020-06-30',
       INTERVAL  '7 DAY'
     ) AS t(d1)
```

Result:

```
d1
2020-06-01
2020-06-08
2020-06-15
2020-06-22
2020-06-29
```

### `cte2`

This adds 6 days to the result of `cte1` to get the end of the week - i.e. every Sunday in June - in fact, it also picks up the first Sunday in July without the `WHERE` clause which the OP apparently doesn't want, so I remove it using the `WHERE`. I take the result of `cte1` and simply put the result of the addition of the `'6 DAY'` beside it:

```
SELECT d1, (d1 + '6 DAY'::INTERVAL)::DATE AS d2
FROM cte1
WHERE (d1 + '6 DAY'::INTERVAL)::DATE < '2020-06-30'::DATE
```

`SELECT * FROM cte2` gives

```
d1          d2
2020-06-01  2020-06-07
2020-06-08  2020-06-14
2020-06-15  2020-06-21
2020-06-22  2020-06-28
```

which are all the dates we need for the OP's requirements.

### `cte3`

In this cte, I use the [`STRING_AGG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html) function which essentially converts a result set into a .csv list - not normally best practice, but given the number of questions about converting back and forth between .csv, very useful and is the OP's requirement. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557563/whats-the-equivalent-for-listagg-in-postgres) helpful.

There was also the problem of this newline character - I wasn't sure that this was possible, but thanks to my friend Mr. Google, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36029083/470530) which explains that one can use either [`E\n`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) or [`CHR(10)`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/chr-function.php) - I tried both and both work fine - the decision here to use `E\n` is arbitrary on my part.

I also added the `(` & `)` brackets at the beginning and end of the `STRING_AGG`.

```
SELECT 
  '(' || 
  STRING_AGG((d1::TEXT) || '-' || (d2::TEXT) || ',', E'\n') 
  || ')' 
  AS date_string1
FROM cte2
```

`SELECT * FROM cte3` gives:

```
date_string1
(2020-06-01-2020-06-07,
2020-06-08-2020-06-14,
2020-06-15-2020-06-21,
2020-06-22-2020-06-28,)
```

So, we're nearly there! The only "fly in the ointment" is the ',)' at the very end - the OP's requirement is for the string to end `2020-06-28)` and not `2020-06-28,)`, so the very last part of the SQL statement is the use of the [`REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) function to remove this final comma.

```
SELECT REPLACE(date_string1, ',)', ')') AS date_string FROM cte3;
```

Et voilà - the result as the OP requested.

p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter:

```
select d::text || '-' || (d + 6)::text
from (
  select date '20200601' + generate_series(0,21,7) d
) x;
```

Remember

1. you can add integers to dates to "add days", and the resulting datatype is still a date rather than the timestamp you get when you add an interval to a date
2. you can specify a `step` parameter to `generate_series`